# OptimumRequest: StackOverflowError

Tags: java

I have StackOverflowError problem in my java code. I tried to inspect and it seems I have infinite recursion. Kindly, please feed me back on how to resolve.

```
public int calculate() {
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        value = calc(0, xstdLen, dataRequest, 1);
    }
    return value;
}

private int calc(int i, int balance, int[] dataR, int totalLen) {
    if (i < len) {
        if (balance >= dataR[i]) {
            value = calc(i + 1, balance - dataR[i], updArr(dataR, i), totalLen);
        } else {
            value = calc(i + 1, balance, dataR, totalLen);
        }
    } else {
        for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
            if (dataR[k] > balance) {
                if (dataR[k] == 0) {
                    value = totalLen;
                } else if (dataR[k] > 0) {
                    value = calc(0, xstdLen, dataR, totalLen + 1);
                }
            } else {
                value = calc(0, balance, dataR, totalLen);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}

private int[] updArr(int[] dataR, int i) {
    if (i > 0) {

    }
    return dataR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `calc()` function calls itself recursively both in the `if` and `else` block, so the last line: `return value;` is never reached.

A recursive function normally needs a stopping condition, that is eventually fulfilled, so that recursion ends.

Since I don't know what you want to calculate, I can't tell how exactly it should look like.

But try to change your `calc()` function so that it has this form. And make sure that the stopping criterion is eventually reached! :

```
private int calc(int i, int balance, int[] dataR, int totalLen) {
    if(\* stopping criterion *\) {
        return value;
    } 
    else if(i < len) {
        \* your recursive if block*\
    } else {
        \* your recursive else block*\
    } 
}
```

That said, your function looks *very* bad in performance. The contained for-loop and the calling for loop together have complexity O(len^2) already. With the recursion I think it's at least O(len^3).

Again, I don't know what you are trying to achieve,  but having a for-loop inside a recursive function is very unusual. Try thinking about how to solve it without the loop.